# Coding solution to WAR installation error (Websphere Portal 6.0)?

Tags: java, jsp, portlet, websphere-portal

I have a Websphere Portal application containing several portlets for which I'm currently working on some changes.

A week ago, the WAR file produced by Rational Application Developer could be installed on the Portal server with no problems.

Yesterday I made some seemingly minor changes to two JSP files and their associated "pagecode" Java files, and attempting to update the WAR on the server (using the Portal Administration web interface) now produces an error message.
The WAR upload works, and the system shows me the correct list of portlets in the WAR file, but clicking "Finish" gives me a page with the error message "EJPAQ1319E: Cannot install the selected WAR file. View Details".
Clicking the "View Details" link gives me a page with the following text:

```
EJPAQ1319E: Cannot install the selected WAR file.
com.ibm.portal.WpsException: EJPAQ1319E: Cannot install the selected WAR file.

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.DoInstallWebModuleAction.installPortletFromFormFile(DoInstallWebModuleAction.java:633)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.DoInstallWebModuleAction.doExecute(DoInstallWebModuleAction.java:159)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.adminstruts.actions.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:64)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.struts.WpsRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(WpsRequestProcessor.java:338)

at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.struts.WpsStrutsPortlet.processActionPerformed(WpsStrutsPortlet.java:1947)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.struts.WpsStrutsPortlet.actionPerformed(WpsStrutsPortlet.java:1637)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.adminstruts.WpsAdminStrutsPortlet.actionPerformed(WpsAdminStrutsPortlet.java:261)

at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.SPIPortletInterceptorImpl.handleEvents(SPIPortletInterceptorImpl.java:323)


EJPPE0020E: It is not allowed to install a JSR 168 compliant over a 4.x portlet application.
com.ibm.wps.command.applications.AppWarFileException: EJPPE0020E: It is not allowed to install a JSR 168 compliant over a 4.x portlet application.

WrappedException is: com.ibm.wps.pe.mgr.exceptions.InvalidWarFileException: EJPPE0020E: It is not allowed to install a JSR 168 compliant over a 4.x portlet application.

at com.ibm.wps.command.applications.AbstractApplicationsCommand.throwAppMgrException(AbstractApplicationsCommand.java:492)

at com.ibm.wps.command.applications.UpdatePortletApplicationCommand.execute(UpdatePortletApplicationCommand.java:165)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.DoInstallWebModuleAction.installPortletFromFormFile(DoInstallWebModuleAction.java:510)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.DoInstallWebModuleAction.doExecute(DoInstallWebModuleAction.java:159)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.adminstruts.actions.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:64)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.struts.WpsRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(WpsRequestProcessor.java:338)

at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.struts.WpsStrutsPortlet.processActionPerformed(WpsStrutsPortlet.java:1947)


EJPPE0020E: It is not allowed to install a JSR 168 compliant over a 4.x portlet application.
com.ibm.wps.pe.mgr.exceptions.InvalidWarFileException: EJPPE0020E: It is not allowed to install a JSR 168 compliant over a 4.x portlet application.

at com.ibm.wps.pe.mgr.AbstractApplicationManagerImpl.updateWebModule(AbstractApplicationManagerImpl.java:1338)

at com.ibm.wps.pe.mgr.AbstractApplicationManagerImpl.updateWebModule(AbstractApplicationManagerImpl.java:1255)

at com.ibm.wps.command.applications.UpdatePortletApplicationCommand.execute(UpdatePortletApplicationCommand.java:135)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.DoInstallWebModuleAction.installPortletFromFormFile(DoInstallWebModuleAction.java:510)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.DoInstallWebModuleAction.doExecute(DoInstallWebModuleAction.java:159)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.adminstruts.actions.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:64)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.struts.WpsRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(WpsRequestProcessor.java:338)

at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)

at com.ibm.wps.portlets.struts.WpsStrutsPortlet.processActionPerformed(WpsStrutsPortlet.java:1947)
```

All I've been able to find about this error via Google is the following in the Websphere Portal documentation:

> **EJPPE0020E:** It is not allowed to install a {0} over a {1} portlet application.
>   **Explanation:** A portlet application containing legacy portlets can only be updated with another portlet application that contains legacy portlets. The same is true for standard portlet applications.
>   **User Response:** Modify the portlet.xml of the application such that it matches the original API type, standard or legacy and try again.

However, the "portlet.xml" file has not changed in about a month, and I've done several WAR updates for this application in that time with no problems. The problem seems to be caused by the code changes I did yesterday, but I have no clue why a few lines of code would do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: might want to post the "few lines of code" changes

Comment: as matt b says, and can you revert to the earlier war and install successfully?

Comment: Never mind - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual cause turned out to be a silly mistake on my part, and nothing to do with the code changes. When using the Portal admin interface to update the WAR, I had selected the wrong existing WAR to update, so I was trying to update one application with something completely different.

Comment: Thanks for posting... I just made the same silly mistake and this saved me some time.